# Wordpress plugin custom options page not accessible

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating my first WP plugin class and seem to be hitting an issue with the options page generation.
I have an admin_init method to create a new page (for now in the top_level menu), which works fine, but clicking on the link in the menu always sends me to the "Your not allowed to access this page" page.

What's odd is that, in debugging the issue, I see that a reference to my page gets added to the $_registered_pages array when the plugin is activated. But when debugging after clicking the link, the $_registered_pages array does not contain a reference to my plugin. Also, after the issue when I return to the site, the menu option is gone.

Here is my admin_init method, which is hooked in the main plugin page:

```
public static function admin_menu() {
    $hook = add_menu_page(
        self::$title,
        self::$menuTitle,
        'manage_options',
        self::$slug,
        array('DP_Quora_Profile_Scraper', 'load_options_page')
    );

    add_action('load-' . $hook, array('DP_Quora_Profile_Scraper', 'save_options_page'));
}
```

The function I'm debugging and seeing the missing page ref is user_can_access_admin_page() in wp-admin/includes/plugin.php

I'm not using the Settings API because I really dislike it, and my plugin needs its own DB table anyway, so I'm encapsulating all my login in my class.

Any thoughts on why/how my menu page is disappearing.

Wordpress version is 5.3. New dev site, no other plugins, default theme.

[EDIT]
Additional screenshot to show debug session: you can see that the $_registered_pages entry does get added.
[image: debug session]

Thank for any, and all, help/comments.
Paul

Comment: the call to `add_menu_page` must be done at every pages. why do you test for `!$initialized` ?

Comment: Tried that but it made no difference. Menu option initially appears, but clicking on it shows the "no access" page, and the $_registered_pages entry is again missing...odd...back to the debugger.

Comment: I found the main problem, the page must be added on the action `admin_menu`. it's written in the notes : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

Comment: Yeah, I'd changed that after your first comment...I'll update my post

Comment: @Kaperto Thx for the nudge in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the issue...most annoying!

My class needed to be initialized along with the hook being registered on every admin_init, and admin_menu.

What a complete load of pointless processing!